# Can you disable VLC's font cache?

Tags: fonts, vlc-media-player

I have *many* fonts installed and VLC's font cache rebuilding takes several minutes.

What is it for? How can I disable it?

Comment: Does it hang at 20%? Does it complete? Does it happen every time?

Comment: @Tom It finished in a little under three minutes to build a 4.68 MB cache file out of 1,582 fonts. Just restarting VLC isn't enough to trigger a cache rebuild; installing a font is. The percentage is no longer shown.

Answer (score 20):

Found this after some digging in the [VLC forums](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=80745). (image by me)

**Building font cache pop-up**

Solution:

1. Open VLC player.
2. On menu bar: Tools/Preferences
3. (At bottom - left side) Show settings -- ALL
4. Open: Video Click: Subtitles/OSD (this is now highlighted, not opened).
5. Text rendering module - change this to "Dummy font renderer function"
6. Save Exit
7. Re-open - done. Progy will no longer look outside self for fonts.

[image]

---

### DISCLAIMER:

You must set your VLC PLayer preferences to "All"

Comment: [Still no joy.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/VLC%20Font%20Cache.png)

Comment: As seen in the link of @harrymc's solution, the portable version makes it worse.

Comment: I don't think this answer covers the current version of VLC player. The user interface for preferences was reworked some time ago. Or it may depend on the platform.

Comment: People, this worked. I just tested using 1.11. Has nobody figured that the "reworked interface" can be just switched back by clicking the "All" button on the bottom left corner?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are left with two options:

1. Recompile the program configured with `--disable-fontconfig`, or modify the source code.
2. Trim down your fonts folder, I don't think you really need all 1500+ there all the time.

   You are probably using less than 33% of them, start by killing the fonts that *take the most size*...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are on Windows 7?

From [disable font cache?](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=78130) :

> Right click on the vlc.exe and select
>   Properties.
>  Click the
>   Compatibility tab and check the box
>   for "Run this program in compatibility
>   mode for", then select "Vista Service
>   Pack 1".
>
> I just did this on Windows 7 and not only does the font cache loading thing not come up, but VLC opens instantly instead of having that couple of seconds delay.

If this doesn't work, I would suggest to totally uninstall VLC using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html), ensure that the installation folder was really deleted, then reinstall. I must remark that I have tried VLC under a Win7 VM, and it had an immediate startup time.

**EDIT**

The discussion at [Rebuilding Font Cache problem in new VLC](http://portableapps.com/node/24005) seems to indicate that this is a problem of the latest VLC version, and that reverting to version 1.0.5 fixes it.

I want to clarify that this is not actually an error, but is a feature by design (see the *portable apps* link above). Every time you install a font, you can expect this to happen. To prevent this from happening in newer versions of VLC, you would actually need to recompile the software/find a recompiled version of the software (again, see link).

Comment: No cigar[.](http://./)

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: An advanced uninstall, followed by reinstall, had me greeted by the font cache rebuild window.

Comment: Added one more edit.

Comment: Why down-vote solutions that worked for some people for exactly the same problem?

Answer (score -2):

I guess you mean "Front Cache". I got the same message since version 1.1.0. I found a solution where you need to delete the cache file in the directory %appdata%/vlc/. That worked for me. The name of the file is something cryptic. Mine was something like `d031bbba323fd9e5b47e0ee5a0353f11-i686.cache-3`

If the problem returns you also can delete the vlc-cache-gen.exe in the Programm Files/VLC folder. VLC will never again generate the cache. I found this suggestion at the same source like the other one above. But I don´t know if that will cause some other problems because I didn´t try deleting the vlc-cache-gen.exe.

Source of solution (german forum): [Chip.de - VLC Media player](http://forum.chip.de/downloads/vlc-media-player-erzeuge-fontcache-1397303.html)

Comment: Nope: I meant _font_ cache. Deleting the font cache causes it to be rebuilt, obviously. I'll try and rename the font cache generating executable then... once it's done generating the font cache obviously >.<

Comment: Renaming the executable did not fix the issue. Process Explorer shows it's VLC itself doing the caching.